# Swift- unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift

This is my code:

```
if let img = UIImage(named: imageName)
{image = img}
else{image = UIImage(named: "default")!
```

However, it still comes up with the error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Need help, thanks!

Comment: Do you have `"default"` as an image in your bundle?

Comment: yes, i have it (default.jpg)

Comment: Try `image = UIImage(named: "default.jpg")!`; leaving the extension off will cause a png to be looked for.

Comment: I try it with UIImage(named: "default.jpg")!
It comes out with another errors

Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/UITableView.m:6245

erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier rProduct Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: @YpNg: ... which is a completely different and unrelated problem (and if you search for that error messages you should find lots of answers to that one).

Comment: @YpNg as @ABakerSmith said you must use default.jpg. For `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` make sure you added delegate for tableview and custom cell is called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)